# Resources To Learn REXX

Tags: rexx

I want to travel in the past and learn [REXX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/rexx/), but I don't know where to start, then I want some help from someone that can point me to the right place to start.

Comment: you can look at the eletronic version of the book "Rexx Programmer's Reference" at: http://www.flazx.com/ebook2613.php and see if the book satisfay your needs and then buy it

Comment: Install OS/2 on virtual box, it comes with Rexx preinstalled! :P

Comment: That's how I learned REXX, i.e. from OS/2.  The rexx programmers reference that comes with it is invaluable.

Comment: Or Amiga Workbench, that's how I learned ARexx :)

Comment: Oh cool. Brings memories back :) I was for 3.5 years at IBM Netherlands involved in maintaining some REXX backend code running at S/390 z/VM which can take XML input and generate XML output and was fronted by under each a JSP/Servlet webapplication which makes use of XSLT to translate REXX's output into JSP/HTML and vice versa. Good ol' times.

Comment: I saw the question title and I was going to suggest a time machine, but it seems you already know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [IBM publib on the subject](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/FINDBOOK?filter=rexx) (which was (is still?) backed by REXX programmed application, at least, during my IBM times, a colleague maintained it). You can find there all **free** books in either HTML or PDF format. The **REXX Guide** (available as [PDF](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/download/DFHWRX00.pdf?DT=20000718112351) or [HTML](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/DFHWRX00/CCONTENTS?DT=20000718112351)) is good to get started. If you intend to run (emulate) it on Windows, I can recommend [Regina Rexx](http://regina-rexx.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 for Regina - it's a solid REXX implementation.  I've used REXX for 20 years, including Mike's version for CMS, and Regina is a good version too.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Open Object ReXX, which came out of IBM object ReXX.  It's on SourceForge.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/oorexx/files/

Documentation starts here - http://www.oorexx.org/docs/

Comment: I have been using Object ReXX for over a decade and find it to be an absolutely rock solid implementation. Highly recommended. Best of all, you can get if for free! This version of ReXX implements both "Classic" ReXX and some pretty nifty OO extentions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to invest some time and money, [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579967) is good (so is [Mike Cowlishaw's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013780735X), but I think that one's out of print and so could perhaps be pricey or slow to get).  If you can't invest the time and/or money, [this tutorial](http://theamericanprogrammer.com/programming/jerexx.shtml) is fast-paced and quick to get through, and gives you good links to other resources.

Comment: +1 for Mike's "The Rexx Language".  If you're an experienced programmer, it's all you'll need.  It's small and digestible, very similar in size and focus to the ancient K&R "The C Programming Language".

Answer (score 2):

Logic at

http://www.kilowattsoftware.com/tutorial/rexx/

Bible - from WROX 
REXX Programmer's Reference - Howard Fosdick

Answer (score 1):

Check out the many resources at the Rexx Language Association ([www.rexxla.org](http://www.rexxla.org)), especially the [links section](http://www.rexxla.org/links).